# Issue with .equals while comparing double in c#

Tags: c#, double

I have a float value that i parsed into double later i rounded off to 2.Also i have another float value to which i did exactly the same as first one.
Here is the sample code..

```
string pulse = arrvaluedline[2].ToString();
pCost = float.Parse(arrvaluedline[3]);

double d = System.Convert.ToDouble(spCost);

double dd = Math.Round(d,2);

string[] arrpulse = pulse.Split(':');

vodanoofPulse = float.Parse(arrpulse[0]);

calculatedCost = CallCost * Pulse;

double dcalcost = Math.Round(calculatedCost, 2);
```

Now here i am trying to compare

```
 if (dcalcost.Equals(spCost)){
 }
```

Although my both values dcalcost and spCost are 0.4 Except this ,flow is not going inside the if ..Why..Please help me .,

Answer (score 4):

**The Equals method should be used with caution**, because two apparently equivalent values can be unequal due to the differing precision of the two values. The following example reports that the Double value `.333333` and the Double value returned by dividing `1 by 3` are unequal.

```
// Initialize two doubles with apparently identical values 
double double1 = .33333;
double double2 = 1/3;
// Compare them for equality
Console.WriteLine(double1.Equals(double2));    // displays false
```

Comparing doubles are not as easy as one might think. Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how you can do it in a better way.

```
// Initialize two doubles with apparently identical values 
double double1 = .333333;
double double2 = (double) 1/3;
// Define the tolerance for variation in their values 
double difference = Math.Abs(double1 * .00001);

if (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= difference)
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are equal.");
else
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are unequal.");
```

Comment: Will parsing double to decimal can do the task

Comment: @user3725571 - why don't you try in your compiler? ;)